# Keyphrase extraction in Python - How to preprocess the text to get better performances

Tags: python, nlp, keyword, text-processing

I'm trying to extract keyphrases from some English texts but I think that the quality of my results is affected by how the sentences are formulated. For example:

Sentence 1

```
import pke

text = "Manufacture of equipment for the production and use of hydrogen."

# define the valid Part-of-Speeches to occur in the graph
pos = {'NOUN', 'PROPN', 'ADJ'}
# define the grammar for selecting the keyphrase candidates
grammar = "NP: {<ADJ>*<NOUN|PROPN>+}"

extractor = pke.unsupervised.PositionRank()
extractor.load_document(input=text, language='en')
extractor.grammar_selection(grammar = grammar)
extractor.candidate_selection(maximum_word_number = 5) 
extractor.candidate_weighting(window = 5, pos = pos) 
keyphrases = extractor.get_n_best(n = 10, redundancy_removal = True)
#dict_keys(['bert', 'state-of-the-art model'])

keyphrases
```

returns this:

```
[('equipment', 0.2712123844387682),
 ('production', 0.24805759926043025),
 ('manufacture', 0.20214941371717332),
 ('use', 0.14005307983173715),
 ('hydrogen', 0.1385275227518909)]
```

While:

Sentence 2

```
text = "Equipment manufacture for hydrogen production and hydrogen use"
```

with the same piece of code returns this:

```
[('hydrogen production', 0.5110246649313613),
 ('hydrogen use', 0.4067693357279659),
 ('equipment manufacture', 0.3619113634611547)]
```

which, in my opinion, is a better result since allows me to understand what we're talking about.

I wonder if there's a way to preprocess Sentence 1 making it more similar to Sentence 2. I've already tried with Neuralcoref but, in this particular case, doesn't help me.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.
Francesca

Comment: There is research on *automatic text simplification* and *paraphrase generation*, but I don't know if either would result in a net improvement – looks like a very difficult problem, especially since it's not clear what makes the second phrase "better" than the first.

Comment: Hi @fsimonjetz, if I have to explain to a human what what makes the second sentence "better" than the first one is the fact that, instead of having very generic words like use or production, I have a detail on what they refer (hydrogen use or hydrogen production). But I don't know how to explain this to a machine :)

Comment: You add a subject matter clause in the rule set. E.g. all phases get evaluated against a list of specific subject matter phrases if they get a hit then the phrase being assessed is more specific than another. - its more work to build up the knowledge base but simple to implement after